# What method/algorithm/library can securely encrypt then decrypt

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

The following project is done in C++ with WinAPI, for encryption/encoding I am using CryptoC++ but I am open to better libraries. I need to encrypt/encode email data, transmit it, then decrypt it at the other end so privileged users can read the email.

My original idea was just to encrypt the email text using SHA256 using my key(eg "MYKEY"). But I think I don't fully understand what hashing is. I understand that a string encrypted with SHA256 or MD5 or AES is impossible to decrypt, BUT I thought that if I encrypt the string with my special key("MYKEY") that I could then decrypt it aslong as I know the special key. Is that correct?

If not can you suggest a library, algorithm or method I can use to achieve my task of encrypting/encoding email text & ONLY being able to decrypt it if I have a key or some shared secret that will allow me to decrypt the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Captain Giraffe, a hash algorithm is not an encryption algorithm (though they are both counted in the area of symmetric cryptography). A good hash function has no way to recover a message which fits to the produced hash (other than trying all possible messages to see if they give the same hash). (And also, a hash function has fixed size output, but has a variable size input, which means that there are many messages giving the same hash. It still should be difficult finding even one pair of messages giving the same hash, or a message for a given hash.)

You need an encryption algorithm. Most probably asymmetric encryption (using public keys to encrypt, private keys to decrypt) is a good idea.

**Don't invent new cryptographic data formats or protocols.** You will make mistakes, which make your product insecure.

For email encryption, use either OpenPGP ([RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)) or S/MIME ([RFC 3851](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3851)), or some subsets of one of these.

You can then use any library which supports the necessary algorithms, or some library which supports specifically these file formats.

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 and MD5 are One way functions. i.e. There is no decryption. See Hashing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function.

But you really need to read up on encryption procedures before attempting to create a secure communication.

That being said wikipedia has an article dedicated to implementations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations